# android AES playstore security warning

Tags: android-security

I use AES algoritm to make a udp request in local subnet (192.168.1.x).
The Playstore shows me a warning because I use static secret key.

```
// Console alert refers to this method
  public byte[] encryptionUtil(String key, String iv, byte[] plainText) {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(“AES/GCM/NoPadding”);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), “AES”);
    GCMParameterSpec paramSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(256, iv.getBytes());
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, paramSpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(plainText);
  }

  // The unsafe key and initialisation vector are here and should be changed
  byte[] cipherText = encryptionUtil(“abcdef...”, “010203040506”, plainText);
```

I'm try to make a iv random and send it in the udp packet, I publish the apk again but the playstore make the warning again.

What is the solution?